# Subtracting string from a string [Android]

Tags: android, string, string-matching

I have following two string:

String one:
"abcabc/xyzxyz/12345/random_num_09/somthing_random.txt"

String Two:
"abcabc/xyzxyz/12345/"

What i want to do is attach path "random_num_09/somthing_random.txt" from string one two string two. So how can i subtract string two from string one and then attach remaining part to string two.

I have tried to do it by searching for the second last "/" in the string one and then doing sub string and attaching it to string two.

But is there any better way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: aren't you simply trying to do `string2 = string1;` ?

Comment: no, i want to append some part from string one to string two.

Comment: can you post an example where the result string2 is different from string1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use substrings, as you said:

```
String string_one = "abcabc/xyzxyz/12345/random_num_09/somthing_random.txt";
String string_two = "abcabc/xyzxyz/12345/";
String result = string_two + string_one.substring(string_one.indexOf(string_two)+1));
```

The other possibility is to use regex, but you would still be doing concatenation to get the result.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(string_two+"(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string_one);
if (m.matches()) {
  String result = string_two+m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

rather that a substring, replace is simpler to use:

```
String string1 = "abcabc/xyzxyz/12345/random_num_09/somthing_random.txt";
String string2 = "abcabc/xyzxyz/12345/";
String res = string2 + string1.replace(string2, "");
```